# Im getting Nan error during subtraction of two times not two dates. can you please help me how to resolve it

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, controller

```
var startDate = component.get("v.time");
        var endDate = component.get("v.time1");
        var days = (endDate-startDate)/8.64;
        alert(days);
```

I'm getting error like Nan during subtraction of two times in lightning controller. can anyone help me how to find the difference between two times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the difference in times, you can use some parsing:

```
update: function(component, event, helper) {
    let start = component.find("start").get("v.value");
    let end = component.find("end").get("v.value");
    if(start && end) {
        let startSec = start.split(/:/).reduce((p,v)=>p*60+parseFloat(v),0);
        let endSec = end.split(/:/).reduce((p,v)=>p*60+parseFloat(v),0);
        component.set(
            "v.diff",
            (endSec-startSec)/60
        );
    } else {
        component.set("v.diff", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: even though im using this same formula getting the same error. actually time1 and time2 are the two input from users.

Comment: @Ajith I just tested this, and it works for me.

Comment: this is working in lightning component right?

Comment: Actually time1 and time2 are two inputs which containing only time. Im not using lightning input type as datetime. Im using ionly time. can you please help me this?

Comment: @Ajith If you don't know the dates, then how would you expect to get the number of days?

Comment: I want to get the number of minutes not dates. My scenario is to find the number of minutes between two times.

Comment: can you help me how to do this?

Comment: suppose my time 1 is 10:00 AM and Time2 is 11:00AM and im expecting the result as 60 mins or 1 hour like that.

Comment: @Ajith That's pretty easy too, just needs more parsing. See updated version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer